# Is there any recommended code to show a specific value in a separate label if any three checkboxes out of six are selected in Vb?

Tags: vb.net

I have created 6 checkboxes in Vb and I want to code that if any three of them are checked then a certain value will be shown in a separate label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd build an Array of your CheckBoxes and wire them up to a common CheckChanged() handler.  Then you can use a simple LINQ query to count the number of them that are checked.

Something like:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private CheckBoxes() As CheckBox

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ' change the below to the names of your six checkboxes:
        CheckBoxes = {CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3, CheckBox4, CheckBox5, CheckBox6}
        For Each cb In CheckBoxes
            AddHandler cb.CheckedChanged, AddressOf CheckBoxes_CheckedChanged
        Next
        Label1.Text = "Select at least three checkboxes."
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBoxes_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If CheckBoxes.Where(Function(cb) cb.Checked).Count >= 3 Then
            Label1.Text = "Thank you!"
        Else
            Label1.Text = "Select at least three checkboxes."
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: There's no need for the loop and the `AddHandler`. You can select all the `CheckBoxes` in the designer, open the *Properties* window, click the *Events* button and then double-click the `CheckedChanged` event to generated an event handler with all the controls in the `Handles` clause. You can then create the list of `CheckBoxes` in the event handler, either explicitly or, if they are all in the same container and they are the only `CheckBoxes` in that container, with LINQ: `Dim checkBoxes = Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()`.

Comment: There's also no need to call `Where` and `Count` as `Count` accepts the same predicates that `Where` does: `If CheckBoxes.Count(Function(cb) cb.Checked) >= 3 Then`.

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinney, I've just always typed it that way with Where() because it "looks right" to me.  Old habits die hard.  As for the other suggestions, definitely more than one way to skin a cat...